# Spring boot service in command line runner with @MockkBean cannot be mocked

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockk, spring-mockk

I have created a small reproducer for an error that I get while I try to test a command line runner application built with Spring boot. I have a simple application with one service

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class MockkBeanFailureApplication(
        private val dummyService: DummyService
) : CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        println(dummyService.hello())
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MockkBeanFailureApplication>(*args)
}
```

and the service is

```kotlin
@Service
class DummyService {

    fun hello(): String {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

I have created the following test that fails to run

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest
class MockkBeanFailureApplicationTests {

    @MockkBean
    lateinit var dummyService: DummyService

    @Test
    fun testMethod(){

        every { dummyService.hello() } returns "Not Hello"
    }

}
```

When I try to run this test, I get the following error

`io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: DummyService(dummyService bean#1).hello()`

I would expect that this should work, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why should it work? You haven't registered any behavior for the mocked bean, so why should it return anything?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? To my understanding, the app runs, and it should use the mocked service bean returning the "Not Hello" value instead of the "Hello" one. How should I register the behavior? Isn't `every` function supposed to do this? I used a similar example as the one described in the documentation (see https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk#principle)

Comment: I'm not familiair with the `every` method and the `@Test` method will always run after the execution of the `CommandLineRunner`. So the behavior is always registered after that. If you want to have the mock with behavior being used you would haev to do all of this in an `@TestConfiguration` and not the test itself. In the documentation you point it works because first the behavior is registered then a method is invoked and verified. That won't work with components that are run by Spring BOot (because they run as part of the lifecycle of the app).